# Xcode pch file can't find boost even though header search path is set and boost is installed

Tags: xcode, boost, pch

My `Foo_Prefix.pch` file can't find boost. I installed boost with `brew` and have added `/usr/local/include` for both Debug and Release in the `Build Settings/Search Paths/Header Search Paths` in `non-recursive` mode. Switching to recursive mode causes different problems, like header files nested too deeply.

The error message is: `Foo_Prefix.pch: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'boost/array.hpp' file not found`

The header file `/usr/local/include/boost/array.hpp` exists. I have cleaned the project and restarted Xcode several times.

Help?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue, I have boost installed in ../../../3p folder relative to the xcode project path. I added the include header path to "Header Search path". .PCH is not locating the boost headers, than I added the same boost include path to "User header Search path" and made "Always Use User path" to Yes. Than it worked. Not sure what is the issue. Of course I am using <> to include boost headers.